# Code Analysis with FXCop (issue after upgrading to 4.5)

Tags: analysis, fxcop

I am using static code analysis and have my own custom rules.

Recently I migrated the project to VS2013 and after that when I am running the build from Team City its throwing the error saying it cannot load the ruleset...

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

what could be the reason, also how can I tell the project to use the latest version of FXCOP?

Regards
Amal Thomas

Comment: Do you see the same problem even if you do not attempt to use the custom rules?

Comment: I think this is a referencing issue in your custom rules. They have to be rebuilt in Visual Studio 2013 to work for the newest FxCop. It uses other version of FxCop dlls.

Comment: Issue resolved by rebuilding the code analysis rule dll in 4.5.. Thanks